# Rails best_in_place gem input has nasty extra space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, best-in-place

I'm using Rails 3.2.3, Twitter Bootstrap, and the best_in_place gem to handle in-place editing.

The problem is that whenever I click to edit input, a bunch of extra space is placed to the right of the input.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Has anyone else had this problem?  What should I do?

I've tried explicitly setting the padding and margin to 0 and the width to a set pixel width - less than the td width.

Thanks.

Comment: i'm looking at this myself - best-in-place relies on rest-in-place, and I see with the input, the default size is 220 px, and there's a css class of rip-active attached to it.  I'm looking at that...

Answer (score 4):

Twitter bootstrap gives you wide range of input sizing classes. like 'input-small', 'input-large' etc.

try adding those classes for 'inner_class' attribute and it should apply on the input field.

```
<%= best_in_place @category, :name, {:inner_class => "input-small", :type => :input} %>
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this issue myself. I passed the html attribute `size` using the `:html_attrs` option available in best_in_place, as follows:

`<%= best_in_place @payment, :currency, :html_attrs => { size: 3 } %>`

A size of 3 means an input box for 3 characters. This substantially reduced the input box expansion in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is actually adding data to your database with extra spaces.

This is just a CSS issue, where your input field is designed to take up a certain percentage of the containing element or something like that. Hard to tell without seeing the exact CSS behind the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I used `cols` and `rows`, as an alternative to `size`:

```
<%= best_in_place @payment, :currency, :html_attrs =>  { :cols => '45', :rows => '10' } %>
```